# How to continuously animate (grow and shrink) objects on site using jquery?

Tags: jquery

How can I animate an object using jquery? It should appear after a while, grow, stay that way for a random number of seconds and then shrink and disappear (this should repeat endlessly). I have tried a few things, but I just can't get it working.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for jQuery [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/). CSS3 [transitions](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp) may be another option to look at if you don't have to use jQuery.

Comment: This annoying bit of code should get you started with an idea: http://jsfiddle.net/PQJSw/1/

Comment: Of course I tried "animate", the problem was, that I never got it running as a whole. I also had problems like this - the circle wouldn't grow/shrink from/to it's center and it didn't disappear completely, 1px * 1px always remained.

Comment: @mVChr - That's only fade in and out, I think that in this case fade isn't even necessary.

Comment: @Drejon Did you find an answer?

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/8sMQF/

Using a few [setIntervals](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp), jQuery [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) and [fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) / [fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/).

Comment: This is much closer. You can take out the fades and set the start/end size to 0px * 0px and the effect works like I imagined. The only thing remaining is, how to completely center it?